# Returning from PayPal to the page that called it

Tags: paypal, return-value

I am hoping someone can help me with the following. I have a Buy Now button on a child dialog. Buy Now button displays PayPal page correctly. Now I am trying to do I cannot find info on it. I would like PayPal to return to the child dialog with a variable that will indicate success (payment made) or failure (payment cancelled by buyer). Is this possible?

The flow works like this:

1. Member logs in to my site
2. Member makes purchase via paypal
3. Member is added to a raffle prize.

The child window (dialog) remains open as PayPal is opened in another page. Regardless of whether the payment is successful or cancelled/ failed I would like to return to the child window with a value indicating the result of the payment. If the result is a success then some code is performed. If not then nothing is done and the child window remains open.

Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a return url input `<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="URLspecificToThisTransaction">`, look here https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics under **Setting The Return URL on Individual Transaction** heading

You also need `Instant Payment Notification – notify_url`
Instant Payment Notification comprises three parts:

Someone pays you.
PayPal POSTs FORM variables to a URL you specify that runs a program to process the variables.
You validate the notification.

look here https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf

Comment: Hi varun - thanks for the quick response. I forgot to add in the description. The child dialog opens paypal in a separate window. My users log in to my site, make a purchase, making that purchase qualifies them to enter a raffle on my site, so I would like paypal to return to the child dialog that is still open, instruct a success or failure, if success process raffle entry, if failure do nothing