# Integrating PayPal with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am hoping someone can help me with the following. I have a Buy Now button. The Buy Now button displays PayPal page correctly in a separate window. Now what I am trying to do I cannot find info on it. I would like PayPal to return to the child dialog with a variable that will indicate success (payment made) or failure (payment cancelled by buyer). Is this possible?

I would like flow to work like this:

1.Member logs in to my site
2.Member clicks on BuyNow
3.PayPal opened in new window
4. Member proceeds/ cancels payment
5. PayPal returns to the web page that invoked it.
5a. If payment made the page is refreshed
5b. If payment not made nothing occurs

Bruno

Comment: Auto Return may be what you are looking for https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning from PayPal to the page that called it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857299/returning-from-paypal-to-the-page-that-called-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it was suggested, you can use Auto-Return to have buyers who pay with a PayPal automatically returned to your site. Set the Auto-Return URL in your account to be the page you want buyers taken to or define the `return_url` value.

If you're using buttons created through your PayPal account there is a place to set a cancel and return URL for buyers to be redirected to.

Not every buyer is guaranteed to return to your site though. They'll still be able to close the browser or navigate elsewhere before the redirect completes.